# Can getting a long-term visa from another Schengen state solve my 90-day stay problem?

Tags: schengen, long-stay-visas

I entered a Schengen state (Latvia) with a short-term tourist visa from Latvia, which allows a 90-day stay every 180 days. However I have to stay 96 days here. Additionally, I got a long-term visa from Estonia on my 80th day of stay in Latvia. So if I exit Schengen from Latvia after 96 days, would this be a problem for me? Would the new long-term visa from Estonia allow an extra 90 days to stay in Schengen for me? Should I exit the Schengen area before my previous 90-day visa expires and re-enter with my Estonia long-term visa again for that additional 6 days?

Comment: In _theory_, there is no lawful way with this combination of visas that you can stay 96 days in Latvia. However, you can stay 90 days in Latvia and then in Estonia another 180 days or a year or whatever the duration of your Estonian visa is. There is no problem leaving Schengen on day 89 and re-entering via Estonia _if you stay in Estonia_. If you re-enter and return to Latvia, you have technically overstayed although it will be hard to catch you. (You don't even have to leave on Day 89, especially if you leave via Estonia after the 96 days, where your long-term visa will not be questioned.)

Comment: Can you go to Russia or Belarus for 6 days during this 96 days period, say, for 3 weekends?

Comment: I should point out, in case the OP does not know, there are no border controls between Latvia and Estonia.

Answer (score 1):

- The comment by Andrew Lazarus pointed out that your Estonian visa doesn't allow you to stay in Latvia any longer. With a valid national D visa, you can visit other Schengen states *as if* you had a Schengen C visa, within the 90/180 limit.
- 96 days is close to 90 and Estonia is close to Latvia. If you manage to get to Estonia over the weekends, say, leaving Latvia on Friday after work and coming back on Monday morning, you might make it work.

Make sure to keep the tickets, hotel receipts, etc. to document your travels if you try that.

Comment: @JonathanReez, I would not advise anybody to *lie* in this regard, both for moral reasons and due to the consequences if he is found out. There might be documentation of the 16 days in question in Estonia, e.g. pay records at work.